# how to check from inside a frame if function exist (from string)

Tags: javascript

You can check if the function exist (with it's name) like this:

```
function a() {};
typeof window['a']; //-> function
```

this works.

but inside a frame it doesn't work:

```
function a() { return 'a' };
a(); //-> a
typeof window['a']; //-> undefined
```

the (typeof window['function name']) returns 'undefined' even so it does exist.

is there a way to check if the function exist from inside a frame?

Comment: That works fine inside a frame.  That's probably a local variable.

Answer (score -1):

you can simple check if(a === undefined) this should work in frame. let me know the results.

also kindly create a js fiddle showing your problem so we can edit your code to solve problem

Comment: funny: the problem is in jsfiddle...so i assumed i't because it's a frame: jsfiddle.net/ezez/Ctcv7

Comment: @user2646784 You can't use `frameset` and `frame`s at jsFiddle. Please add some real code to your question.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ezez/Ctcv7